# css margin right does not seem to work

Tags: css, margin

https://jsfiddle.net/m4ewm67w/3/

I have crafted this little demo above that the right margin for the items in the container doesn't seem to work. The top, bottom and left margin are working. I'm wondering if I have understood some concept totally wrong.

My html and css code here:

```
<style>
div.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  /* padding: 4px; */
}

div.item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px 100px 5px 5px; 
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the width:100% and it will work

Comment: @TemaniAfif but removing %100 yields undesirable result, yet I don't want to hard code the width in the `.item`s.

Comment: the undesirable result is the big value of margin ;) adjust it and see

Comment: for reading : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth

Comment: I see. It looks like I was  hoping to let the children to push the parent towards the right direction, however the parent already has a fixed width. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

```
div.item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px 100px 5px 5px; 
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Try that ;) the problem was the width

Comment: the problem was not simply the width, i guess it need more deep explanation ...

Comment: if you don't want to hardcode the width here's the solution:

`div.item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px 100px 5px 5px; 
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}`

I hope it helped you.